# call javascript within vb code load function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I’m trying to call Java script code from within the page_load function code, but I don’t know how!!

I’ve added js file to the solution
And put in the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hide.js">
// to hide
getElementById("GradesH3").style.display="none";
getElementById("GradesUL").style.display="none";
</script>
```

Now the code where I want to call it is :

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Session("UsrRole") = "Rector" Then

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is:

```
If Session("UsrRole") = "Rector" Then
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("hide", "js/hide.js")
End If
```

Remove your existing JS code and change the file "hide.js" to contain this code instead:

```
window.onload = function() {
   getElementById("GradesH3").style.display = "none";
   getElementById("GradesUL").style.display = "none";
};
```

Edit: on second thought, more correct way to do that, without using JS at all, it to make `GradesH3` and `GradesUL` be server side by adding `runat="server"` to them then have such code instead:

```
If Session("UsrRole") = "Rector" Then
   GradesH3.Visible = False
   GradesUL.Visible = False
End If
```

You can have any HTML element become server side, for example:

```html
<h3 id="GradesH3" runat="server">I'm header</h3>
```

Comment: Cheers, hope you ended up using the second way? (without JS)

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to achieve what you want.

One is to simply output the javascript from your `Page_Load` - either directly or into a `Literal` control.

Another is to put the javascript statements into a functions and again, in the page load output a script tag calling the function.

Possibly, the best approach it to use server side controls and control their visibility directly, instead of using javascript.